# uninstall another application before installing msi package

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, custom-action, windows-installer

I have a setup project 'B' in VS2008. I want check for whether an application 'A' is installed on a machine or not. If it is installed, then before installation of application 'B' I want to uninstall application 'A'. Is there any way to do this? I searched online, I found many articles which says about upgrade code and all. But, in my case it's not upgrade. I just want to remove another application 'A' which is interrupting my application 'B' behavior.

Note: Application 'A' is also a setup project developed in VS2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the upgradecode is what you need, EVEN if your A application is not an older version of B. Windows Installer supports removing this application if you add its upgradecode in the Upgrade table from B.

For this to work Windows has two major requirements, A and B must have the same installations type, i.e. they both must be per user or per machine, and they also must have the same installation language.